# console.log(typeof) in browser and terminal (node)

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

when you run sample.js file with node in terminal

```
var name = 12;
console.log( typeof name )
//number
```

but it's different in browser console

```
var name = 12;
console.log( typeof name )
//string
```

why there's difference?!

Comment: MDN [`window.name`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/name)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`name` is a property of [`window`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/name) and a string.

When you set `name` in the console, it's actually setting the value of `window.name` which gets converted to a string, as stated in the documentation:

> window.name will convert all values to their string representations by using the toString method.

This particularly happens because you are setting name like so:

```js
var name = 12;
```

Using `var name =`, in a browser, without any other scoping is the same as writing `window.name =`.

However, if you were to use `const` or `let` to declare `name`, then `name` would not apply to the global scope, i.e. `window`, and it would be of the expected type:

```js
const name = 4;
console.log(typeof name)
```